# In Dropbox, how can I tell the date and time when a file was shared?

Tags: file-sharing, dropbox, date-time

I have shared a directory (folder) with another Dropbox user.  Over the course of several weeks, this user has shared a number of files with me.

I need to determine the date and time when these files were shared.  Is it possible to find this information anywhere?

My Dropbox client is running on a Windows XP SP3 (32-bit Home Edition) netbook.  The client does not have much information about the files (except for the location of the Dropbox folder on my hard drive).  The only metadata that Dropbox's web interface shows is the file's type (document, picture, etc.) and last modified date and time.

Comment: This is an old question with an accepted answer that was "reactivated" by a new post.  My reading of the question is that you were asking to know when a file was accessed.  The accepted answer seems to talk about when the file was made shareable.  For the benefit of others with a similar problem, could you clarify which the question refers to?

Comment: @fixer1234 I wished to find out when a file was shared, not accessed last.  The accepted answer addressed that need perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Dropbox, you can only share folders not files. Every file you put into the shared folder gets shared.
If you want to find out when a file was first shared,  find out the date when the file was created in or moved in the shared folder.
2 ways to do this:
 1. go to the Dropbox website, click on "Events", find out the creation date of the files you're interested in. 
 2. To find out the creation date of a specific file, first locate it on Dropbox website, right-click on it, then select "previous versions".

Comment: This is not entirely correct. You can share single files outside a shared folder from Dropbox.

Comment: Whoa!  I didn't know about the "right-click" context menu.  I don't care about the directory share date, so this solution works for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to track the date and time that your Dropbox files have been downloaded using Orangedox: http://orangedox.com/?c=LD This allows you to track you downloads and analytics.

Comment: This names a tool but doesn't explain how to solve the problem.  Can you expand your answer?  Also, if you have any association with the product, please disclose it in your answer.  Thanks.